# Why was Gigi Hadid uncredited for 10 episodes of Silent Witness when she appeared?

Tags: production, film-techniques, credits, cameo

Looking at Gigi Hadid's [IMDb page](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm4676882/), I noticed she'd been in 10 episodes of Silent Witness (a BBC drama).

Is it normal for a celebrity to make appearances like this uncredited? I know normally that uncredited cameos are made in movies, but on a TV series, across two years?

In general, how common is it for American actors to make uncredited appearances on British TV shows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are some actors uncredited in certain films?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15756/why-are-some-actors-uncredited-in-certain-films)

Comment: I think this particular case is actually a different question; the answers on the dupe work in general, but not for this particular case. I do have a feeling this one could be 'my friend Bob/Jeff/John works on the show & got me a couple of days as background'. I'm working on it from next Monday, so I'm going to ask ;)

Comment: Was she actually in this show? You'd think there'd be screencaps etc., yet there is no evidence of her presence. Isn't this a case of someone adding false information to IMDb?

Comment: I was only on the show a couple of days & I forgot to ask [well... didn't find an appropriate person/moment], so this will have to live on as pure speculation, at least for now. I'd like to see the question & answer survive as an example of what can be done to 'game' IMDB, though I'm not sure if it's possible or not to blatantly 'lie' about appearances. I've never tested IMDB's detection policy for that type of subterfuge.

Answer (score 5):

Though this may be a duplicate of [Why are some actors uncredited in certain films?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15756/why-are-some-actors-uncredited-in-certain-films) I felt it worth adding this point, that some people may not be aware of.

Her IMDB page credits her as "Policewoman" - no character name.

This is a classic sign that someone is adding their own IMDB credits as an "actor" when in fact all they were was a Supporting Artist... an Extra.

There are some extras doing this to such an extent that it actually boosts their popularity rating on the *StarMeter* above that of some genuinely famous actors.

A busy extra can work on 100 shows/movies a year.
A good jobbing actor/day player maybe 20.
A Hollywood A-Lister perhaps only 2.

This allows extras to 'game' the system & artificially push their popularity higher... a practise I personally find despicable.
If they walk past in the background in 4 Hollywood blockbusters in a year - so far back even their grandmother wouldn't recognise them in it - then self-accreditation gives them the same amount of 'popularity' as the A-List actor who spent 2 months in front of the camera doing all the actual acting.

I got two lines in a movie I worked on last week, as "Local#1" - scripted dialog which actually entitles me to a credit, (rather than the 1st AD saying, 'could one of you shout "Hey You!"' - which wouldn't).
Will I be putting that on my IMDB page?
I will not.

Comment: I would!  And I'll be bragging about it for a while! Still, yeah,  I agree with your answer.