# Why was Edward Norton's name not featured in the cast of Alita Battle Angel?

Tags: casting, credits, alita-battle-angel

We can clearly see the Edward Norton plays Nova in Alita Battle Angel, but his name was not featured in the end credits of the movie.

I checked IMDb as well which didn't show his name.
What is the reason for this?

Comment: He's listed in the [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0437086/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast), but listed as Uncredited. It could be because Norton only had a Cameo.

Comment: Maybe he wanted to hide his identity to surprise people?

Comment: Related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15756/why-are-some-actors-uncredited-in-certain-films

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](https://www.inverse.com/article/53344-alita-battle-angel-ending-cameo-edward-norton-explained-who-is-nova):

> In interviews with director Robert Rodriguez, he revealed that **the surprise casting is meant to lock in capable actors for big roles in future *Alita* sequels**, which was a lot tougher to pull off than it looks.

Note that the lack of credit might not solely be due to the surprise effect, but also [because of a technicality](https://www.digitalspy.com/movies/a26144773/alita-battle-angel-cameo-edward-norton-nova-james-cameron/):

> "I tried to find somebody who had a real intelligence to them. We went through a list of people that we could find who were worth bothering to do this, because **there's no dialogue or anything.** It's really for the setup of, if there was a sequel. We want to put someone here who we would want in a sequel. So it's kind of tough casting to do.

Answer (score 1):

Norton makes a lot of cameos vs the number of his actual appearances. Norton in the past has expressed sentimentality to embracing character's ["mysteriousness"](http://www.contactmusic.com/edward-norton/news/norton-explains-his-uncredited-role-in-kingdom-of-heaven). I believe his cameo this time was to be a dead-ringer for [James Cameron](https://www.digitalspy.com/movies/a26144773/alita-battle-angel-cameo-edward-norton-nova-james-cameron/) and thus went uncredited to add to the illusion.